# Creating Loadbalancer using AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am trying to create a Loadbalancer using AWS java sdk.
But i am getting AmazonServiceException with Status code as 400, but other fields (like AWS request id, AWS error code etc) are null. I am not able to get what is the issue.

Below is the code snippet i am using to create loadbalancer.

```
    elb = new AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient(credentials);
    elb.setEndpoint("endPoint");



    CreateLoadBalancerRequest lbRequest = new CreateLoadBalancerRequest();
    lbRequest.setLoadBalancerName(lbName);
    List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>(1);
    listeners.add(new Listener(lbProtocol, lbPort, instancePort));
    lbRequest.withAvailabilityZones(availablezone1,availablezone2);
    lbRequest.setListeners(listeners);
    try{
         CreateLoadBalancerResult lbResult = elb.createLoadBalancer(lbRequest);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (AmazonClientException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting the below exception:

Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing, AWS Request ID: null, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: null
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:583)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:167)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancing.AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.invoke(AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.java:1224)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticloadbalancing.AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.createLoadBalancer(AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient.java:675)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change to endpoint to something like: https://elasticloadbalancing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com